# Websocket not working after switching https from http

Tags: apache, ssl, websocket, ratchet

I recently switched my application to https, everything is working fine except for websockets. If I am trying  to connect to my server using the address `ws://ws.myserver.com:8080/` I get the following error now:

SecurityError: The operation is insecure.

If i am using `wss://ws.myserver.com:8080/` i got below error

Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at `wss://ws.myserver.com:8080/`

I am using Apache server and my Ratchet Websocket server is running in it.

Comment: Do you embed the ws-Connection inside a https page, i.e. mixed content?

Comment: Yes.The Client side code is written by using pure javascript and that is embeded in the pages

Comment: Do you have a certificate for ws.myserver.com ? If not, run the websocket on the main domain name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the comments the site is using insecure ws:// inside a secure site (https://). This mixed content is blocked by several browsers, like Firefox and Chrome which results in the "SecurityError: The operation is insecure." message.

Answer (score 0):

If your server is serving both secure and insecure content you'll have to serve these from different ports.

E.g:

If you serve non-secure content on port 8080 you'll have to serve secure content over 443 (the default for wss/https) or any other, like 8443, etc.